# Apache2 virtual hosts not working

Tags: debian, apache-httpd

I use Debian 7 and have installed a virtual host with address sub.domain.com following this tutorial: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/412

I have enabled it, rebooted the PC but still the subdomain opens /var/www

Here is the file contents of the file named "sub.domain.com", located at /etc/apache2/sites-available/ :

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/destfolder
    ServerAdmin info@domain.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/sub.domain.com-error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/sub.domain.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

By the way when I reload apache's configuration, I get:
`NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts`

Any suggestions?

Comment: it should be `<VirtualHost *:80>`  not `<VirtualHost *>`

Comment: @Rahul Patil Can you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 4):

In your Configuration , it should be `<VirtualHost *:80>` not `<VirtualHost *>`

To test the Apache configuration file for errors, use the following command:

```
apachectl configtest
```

If the configuration file is fine, this command will return Syntax Ok. Otherwise, it will return detailed information about the error discovered.

If you are using Redhat based OS then you can use :

```
httpd -t
```